# Can an Afghan citizen get the German work visa without interviewing?

Tags: germany

Can an Afghan citizen get the work visa of Germany where he is not going be asked for the interview, he is not asked of his bank account, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are an Afghan national residing in Afghanistan, No. You have to attend an appointment to submit your travel document and supporting papers, and to provide your biometrics.